# C# Need advice on reading large Excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, interop

My program is required to read a large Excel workbook which has 4-5 sheets with roughly 35000 cells. The biggest  problem that almost every cell is linked to cell in other large workbooks in a computer network.

It's is also required that user chooses a sheet to read data from first.

I tried Excel Interop, but the program just freezes while trying to open a workbook.

Comment: Try "Syncfusion". .

Comment: I got good results with NPOI and it is Open Source.

Comment: I would consider re-engineering the entire solution.  This should like a perfect case of "just because you can, doesn't mean you should."  It's impossible to suggest a solution without knowing more about your process and content, but I think your best bet in most case would be to stage the data from the spreadsheet somewhere else (like a DBMS) and mine it from there.

Comment: How are you reading the book? If you are looping over all cells and calling `Value` each time, the performance will be horrendous. Try reading the range into an array by calling `Value` on the range, then readin the values from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try ClosedXML: https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml This doesn't solve the size problem but I don't know of anything that will except using a database.

Answer (score 0):

ClosedXML is a good library, but I believe that NetOffice.Excel is better, see https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetOffice.Excel/. It does almost the same stuff as Interop, but better.